# Split a long string into an array of shorter strings

Tags: c#

How can I split a string of around 300 (n) words into an array of n/30 strings of 30 words?

Comment: @Mark: I've edited the question for clarity, feel free to amend as you see fit. Vector :- just an easy to use data structure, like an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Regex.Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx):

```
string[] bits = Regex.Matches(input, @"\w+(?:\W+\w+){0,29}")
                     .Cast<Match>()
                     .Select(match => match.Value)
                     .ToArray();
```

See it working online: [ideone](https://ideone.com/8Llmt)

Comment: It ignores the first character of each item.

Comment: @Nick Binnet: I've updated the answer with a link to an example showing the code working correctly. Could you please explain what you mean by "It ignores the first character of each item"? I don't understand what you mean and the output doesn't seem to have any "ignored characters".

Comment: sorry to misunderstand your answer. My bad, I was trying this for a different purpose.

Answer (score 2):

A Regex split would make sense if you have a very large or a very small of characters that can be a part of your string. Alternatively, you can use the Substring method of the String class to get the desired result:

```
        string input = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        const int INTERVAL = 5;

        List<string> lst = new List<string>();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < input.Length)
        {
            string sub = input.Substring(i, i + INTERVAL < input.Length ? INTERVAL : input.Length - i);
            Console.WriteLine(sub);
            lst.Add(sub);
            i += INTERVAL;
        }
```